# Populate list with same object efficiently

Tags: r, list, memory-management

Suppose I have some object (any object), for example:

```
X <- array(NA,dim=c(2,2))
```

Also I have some list:

```
L <- list()
```

I want `L[[1]]`, `L[[2]]`, `L[[3]]`,...,`L[[100]]`,...,`L[[1000]]` all to have the object `X` inside it. That is, if I type into the console `L[[i]]`, it will return `X`, where i is in {1,2,...,1000}.

How do I do this efficiently without relying on a `for loop` or `lapply`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a list of 1 and replicate it.

```
L <- rep(list(x), 1000)
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `replicate` even if it still a kind of a loop solution:

```
L <- replicate(1000,X,simplify=FALSE)
```

**EDIT** benchmarkking the 2 solutions :

```
X <- array(NA,dim=c(2,2))
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark( rep(list(X), 10000),
               replicate(10000,X,simplify=FALSE))

                              expr      min       lq    median        uq      max neval
                  rep(list(X), 10000) 1.743070 2.114173  3.088678  5.178768 25.62722   100
replicate(10000, X, simplify = FALSE) 5.977105 7.573593 10.557783 13.647407 80.69774   100
```

`rep` is 5 times faster. I guess since `replicate` will evaluate the expression at each iteration.